# Python replace value in 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to replace a value in a specific index with specific value retrieved from excel. I'm getting my whole array being replace with the last value retrieved.

```
details= [[""] * 2 ] * 2
details_index=3
for count1 in range(len(details)-1):
    details[count1][0] = sheet.cell(row=count1+2, column=details_index).value
```

the output always return

```
[['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', ''], ['0009', '']]
```

any idea what did the loop did wrong?

Comment: You have a list of other lists that point to the same data. Use `details=[ ["" for column in range(2)] for row in range(2)]` instead.

Comment: See [How to clone or copy a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply arrays you are referring to the pointer of the array and not making a copy.

`[[""]*2]*2` is making `[["",""]*["",""]]`

but actually you only have ["",""] in memory. Therefore, if You change one of those you change all of them.

That is, if you take `array[0][0] = ["9","0"]` you take the location in memory and say `["",""]` is now `["9", "0"]` and so `array = [["9","0"],["9","0"]]`.

One way to solve this is by using deepcopy which you can use by `import deepcopy from copy`

I think that is what you are asking.